# AutoFilter is turned off after an AdvancedFilter is applied

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter, advanced-filter

Let's say I have a `Range("A1", "D13")` in my `Worksheet("Sheet1")` with data. Some data in the first column are repeating, meaning not unique for the column. Now as my first action, I create an `.AutoFilter` for that range:

```
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Set Ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

If Not Ws.AutoFilterMode Then
    Ws.Range("A1", "D13").AutoFilter
End If
MsgBox "AutoFilterMode is " & Ws.AutoFilterMode
```

When I run this, I get drop-down arrows currently displayed on the first row of my range and `Ws.AutoFilterMode` returns `True`.

Now I decide to apply an `.AdvancedFilter` on the first column of my range.

```
Range("A1", "A13").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, Unique:=True
MsgBox "FilterMode is " & Ws.FilterMode
MsgBox "AutoFilterMode is " & Ws.AutoFilterMode
```

When I start the subroutine again, the `.AdvancedFilter` hides the rows where data were repeating in the first column of the range and that is why `Ws.FilterMode` returns `True`, but what I haven't expected is that now `.AutoFilter` is turned off and `Ws.AutoFilterMode` returns `False`.

My workaround on this behavior is to recreate (turn on?) the same `.AutoFilter` right after an `.AdvancedFilter` has applied and if you have a better solution I would be happy to hear it, but what I really am asking here is:

- Is the `.Autofilter` destroyed or simply turned off (by `AutoFilterMode=False`) and is there a difference between the two?
- How `.Autofilter` and `.AdvancedFilter` are connected to produce this behavior?
- Is this an intentional design and if yes what is the gain? If not, do I treat it as a bug, applying my workaround (or a better one if exists) and hoping for the best?

Thank you for your time to read my question and help me.

Comment: You can only apply one or the other (same in the UI).

Comment: @Rory Thank you for answering me and yes that is the behavior I am describing, but I am looking for a deeper explanation.

Comment: Talk to Microsoft then. ;) who else could tell you why they made it that way?

Comment: What does it help if you know **why** you can't have both at the same time? It doesn't change the fact that you just can't.

Comment: @Peh First of all, thank you for editing my post. I would like to know for educational purposes. Plus if something is designed like that on purpose, maybe there must be something to be gained in certain situations and I would like to know about it. Know how actually things work leads to better code.